# D3js Multi line graph convert from using CSV file

Tags: php, arrays, d3.js

I am looking to make a multi line graph from [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4db972df5d7efc7d611255d1cc6f3c4f).

Instead of using data from a CSV file I'm building an array of values from the database:

```
$token_prices = sw::shared()->prices->getForTokenID($token_id);
$token_prices_array = array();

foreach ($token_prices as $token_price) {
    $token_prices_array[] = [
        "date" => $token_price['date'],
        "close" => $token_price['close']
    ];
}

$second_token_prices = sw::shared()->prices->getForTokenID(3);
$second_token_prices_array = array();

foreach ($second_token_prices as $second_token_price) {
    $second_token_prices_array[] = [
        "date" => $second_token_price['date'],
        "close" => $second_token_price['close']
    ];
}

$all = array_merge($second_token_prices_array, $token_prices_array);

foreach ($all as $datapoint) {
    $result[$datapoint['date']] []= $datapoint['close'];
}
```

Data output:

```
{"15-Jun-18":["8.4","0.14559"],"16-Jun-18":["8.36","0.147207"],"17-Jun-18":["8.42","0.13422"],"18-Jun-18":["8.71","0.146177"],"19-Jun-18":["8.62","0.138188"],"20-Jun-18":["8.45","0.128201"],
```

My issue is with plugging the data from the database in:

```
var tokendata = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;

data = tokendata;

 data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
      d.open = +d.open;
  });
```

I get an issue here "data.forEach is not a function"...

How can I fix this to use the data from the database?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2dwgc65/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are embedding the results of the query php page as a JSON string -- if you want to iterate over that data as an array, you will have to parse it back into a Javascript object first.

I'm assuming that the first code snippet is running on a different server, and so the `$result` array is not directly available to your javascript code -- is this why you are trying to set a variable to the encoded return value? If so, it's not the best way to pull data into your page's script, but this may work for you:

```
var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($result)?>');
```

or even:

```
var data = eval(<?php echo json_encode($result)?>);
```

Both methods assume that your result is returned as a valid json string, since there is no error checking or try/catch logic. I honestly don't know what the output of the `json_encode()` method looks like, so if you still can't get it working, please update your post with an example of the returned string.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input - I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ..... heres output: var data = JSON.parse("{"15-Jun-18":["8.4","0.14559"],"16-Jun-18":["8.36","0.147207"]}");

Comment: Looks like you don't need the double quotes around the php output string...

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a different error now: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse. I've updated the original post to show how the array is structured/output

Comment: Thanks for the update -- much easier to see the data now. Since your output json is using double quotes for keys and string values, I would try using single quotes around the `<?php ...?>` substitution (as I've done in the updated example). That may still fail if you have any single quotes inside the data -- in which case it looks like you will need to use the `eval(...)` function.